# Angular 6 reactive forms get key-name

Tags: typescript, angular6, angular-reactive-forms

i use Angular 6, reactive forms. How can i get the keys from my forms -> i mean not the value.

```js
 mainForm = this.fb.group({
    personForm: this.fb.group({
      name: ['', Validators.required],
      surname: ['', Validators.required],
      age: ['', Validators.required]
    }),
    adressForm: this.fb.group({
      street: [''],
      country: ['', Validators.required]
    })
  });
```

I would like to have everything dynamic in the summary page of the form. It should display Name: user-input (value), surname: user-input, age: user-input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Object.keys(this.mainForm.controls)
```

Will give you personForm and addressForm

```
Object.keys(this.mainForm.controls["adressForm"].controls)
```

Will give you the nested values.